# Show view/point/smt under clipped area

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to show something under clipped area?
For example I have:

`UIView *viewA = ...
viewA.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
viewA.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`

So, here I have view with rounded corners. Then I want to add another viewB as subview of viewA and present it under clipped area of viewA. Help me, please, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you want viewB to be clipped too or that it is shown in the clipped area?
If it is the former:

```
viewA.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIView *viewB = ...
viewB.frame = ... // something relative to viewA.bounds
[viewA addSubview:viewB];
```

EDIT:
Then for what you want to do you have to set `viewA.clipsToBounds = YES`, create a container view for both `viewA` and `viewB` and put them both as subviews of this container. You can't clip a superview and have an unclipped subview.

Comment: Actually, I don't want viewB to be clipped, but it must be the subview of  viewA and be under viewA clipped area.

Comment: So you want viewA to be clipped, viewB to be subview of viewA and viewB to not be clipped?

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Yes. It's a moving point and it can be shown not only in viewA, but also under clipped area.
As example: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cropperview
Imagine, that this big image have rounded corners and you want move blue point under clipped area.